# explain malloc, free, and size of object

Tags: c

I tried test `malloc` and `free` by assign new memory to a pointer by calling mallac and then free it, but value return by sizeof does not change at all. I thought that when a pointer is declared, it would get some memory which is represented by value returned by `sizeof`; when I call malloc, its size should be change according to the value of the argument; and finally when I call free, its size is 0. I bet what I thought is incorrect. Can someone help me?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    char *p;

    printf("size of p : %d\n", sizeof(p));

    p = malloc(256);

    printf("size of p : %d\n", sizeof(p));

    free(p);

    printf("size of p : %d\n", sizeof(p));

    printf("Allocate new storage\n");
    p = (char *)malloc(1);

    printf("size of p : %d\n", sizeof(p));

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: `p` doesn't change size; it remains a `char *` throughout the code.  The amount of memory `p` points at varies, but not the size of `p` itself.

Comment: Even you try sizeof(*p), then they will all return 1.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler so when I need to call malloc? what happen if I do not? and How I can figure how many amount of memory I should allocate to the pointer?

Comment: First thing you should know is that pointer+malloc is a common way to dynamically create an array. So answer is, it depends on how big you want the array to be. You are not allocating memory to create a pointer, you are allocating memory and let that pointer point to it.

Comment: You need to call `malloc()` when you need to allocate some memory at runtime, especially when you don't know at compile time how much memory you will need.  If you don't allocate memory and make sure your pointer points at it — or that the pointer points at some other memory — then you get 'undefined behaviour', which is a way of saying "anything could happen" (search for 'nasal demons' to see what I mean).  You figure out how much memory to request by knowing what you want to store in it.  If necessary, you can increase the amount of memory allocated with `realloc()`.

Comment: @user3528438 is there any way to estimate the memory need for the array so that I can allocate it with malloc?

Comment: @PMH you need `object count` * `object size in bytes` memory

Comment: If you need enough space for 32 character string, you need to allocate at least 33 bytes via `malloc()` — the extra byte is needed for the `'\0'` at the end of the string.  If you need enough space for a 32-element array of doubles, you need to use `double *dptr = malloc(32 * sizeof(*dptr));` or something similar.  (You should also check that your memory allocation was successful before using the pointer — though it is safe to pass it immediately to `free()` since `free(NULL)` is safe.)

Comment: for example, if you want int array[100] but dynamically allocated on heap, do int *pArray = malloc(100*sizeof(int));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That kind of information is handled by the OS memory manager. `sizeof(p)` will give you the size of the actual pointer, `sizeof(*p)` will give you the size of the object it points to, but not the actual size of the dynamic allocation.

Usually, the allocated memory has a small header just before the actual data, which holds the information the OS needs to be able to de-allocate it properly, although it is entirely implementation defined. This is why you only need to specify how much memory you want to allocate, but `free()` doesn't need that, it is the memory management responsibility to handle that. Typically you will not have any access to that, nor do you need any.

Comment: as you said, the size of the object that the pointer points to does not related to the size of dynamic allocation. So why need to call malloc? How I can figure how many amount of memory I should allocate to the pointer?

Comment: Allocate as much as you need. You are guaranteed to get at least that much memory if the allocation succeeds (if you have enough free memory). `malloc` is needed when automatic storage is not an option, for example to allocate an object which will remain "alive" after the function it was created in returns, also when the memory is too big to fit on the stack, which is usually a few MBs only, if you need more you will need to use dynamic allocation.

Answer (score 1):

When you do `sizeof(p)`, you will get back the size of char* since `p` is a char*.

There is no standard way in C to get the size of a block of memory you dynamically allocated other than to just keep track of it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 
     malloc_usable_size(p);

to get the size of the dynamically allocated variable.